# Write list to file

Tags: python, list, text-files

I have a folder of `.tif` files, and I would like to write their filenames to a `.txt` or `.csv` file without the file extension, using python. This should be pretty simple but for some reason I always end up with an empty text file. Can anyone see something in my code that I am doing wrong? It prints the names correctly so I know there is no problem with the `.rstrip` command.

```
# import os so you get the os access methods
import os

# set a directory the files are in
workingDir = r'F:\filepath\files'

# get a list of all the files in the directory
names = os.listdir(workingDir)

#print file names
for name in names:
    listname=name.rstrip('.tif')
    print listname


#write filenames to text file
target = open("F:\filepath\list.txt", "w")

for name in names:
    listname=name.rstrip('.tif')
    target.writelines(listname)
    target.writelines("\n")

target.close
```

Answer (score 7):

You forgot to actually call the `close` method at the end of your program.  Add `()` after it to do this:

```
target.close()
```

On some systems (presumably yours), you must close the file to commit the changes.

---

Or, even better, you can use a [with-statement](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-with-statement) to open the file, which will automatically close it for you:

```
with open("F:\filepath\list.txt", "w") as target:
    for name in names:
        listname=name.rstrip('.tif')
        target.writelines(listname)
        target.writelines("\n")
```